# listfield in tabs blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, tabs, listfield

I have a Mainscreen with tabs. Each tab has its own overridden navigationClick method that looks like this

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    fieldChangeNotify(1);
    return true;
}
```

and other methods

```
public boolean isFocusable() {
    return true;
}

protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics,
                         boolean on) {
    // Don't draw the default focus
}

protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    super.onFocus(direction);
    invalidate();
}

protected void onUnfocus() {
    super.onUnfocus();
    invalidate();
}
```

However, in my mainscreen, there is 3 of these tabs in a horizontalfieldmanager. An overridden fieldChanged is implemented like this

```
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    if (_tabArea != null) {
        if (field == _tab1) {
           delete(_tabArea);
            _tabArea = displayTab1();
           add(_tabArea);

        } else if (field == _tab2) {
            delete(_tabArea);
            _tabArea = displayTab2();
            add(_tabArea);
        } else if (field == _tab3) {
            delete(_tabArea);
            _tabArea = displayTab3();
            add(_tabArea);
        }
    }
}
```

which switches the tabs. I have a navigationClick below that handles the clicks on the listfield, however ever since I overrode the navigationClick, that tab switching no longer works. Anyone have any idea why?

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
      Field field = _listfield;

      if(field instanceof ListField)
      {
          int selected = _listfield.getSelectedIndex();
          switch (selected) {
          case 0:
              delete(_tabArea);
              All all = new All();
              _tabArea = all.getVFM();
              add(_tabArea);
              break;
          case 1:
              break;
          }
          return true;
      }
      return super.navigationClick(status, time);   
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your override call super.navigationClick() in all cases?

Based on your code for navigationClick, it looks like super.navigationClick() won't be called, because `if(field instanceof ListField)` prevents execution from reaching the super call.

Comment: I changed the Field field = _listfield; to Field field = this.getFieldWithFocus(); ... Now the tabs work but selecting the list items don't work

Comment: I think instead of using this.getFieldWithFocus(). Do something like if (field.isFocus()) { // your code // } 

It's probably stuffing up because it's triggering when you focus on other fields.